# CSRF Tokens in Web Applications

Tags: web-applications, token, csrf

What is the use of CSRF tokens in web applications. I have gone through many links but getting very much confused.
Who issues the CSRF tokens and how it is validated. I am looking for a complete flow with a request and a response.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: CSRF is used to prevent bots for submitting forms rapidly. After each pageview you need to generate an automatic uniq 'token'. See more about [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: So how this token is validated? I mean server should also contain a token to verify whether the req is correct and not the false one.. So how server has a token? That's my actual confusion.

Comment: depends on what type of programming language you use. Some people do this with PHP and session tokens, other stores the key in a file and compare it on the server-side and so on.

Comment: ok.. lets consider a basic example found in almost all links-https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) What if my bank has an OTP feature implemented that will be send on user's phn no.. attacker obviously dont have access to user's phn no..so can we say that OTP as an CSRF token?

Comment: Yes, but I recommend you to use uniq generated tokens as the attacker still can do attacks to get the OTP of the user.

Comment: okies... so we need to generate tokens for every request or it can be generated for a user single sign-in.